# NameError: name 'check_balance' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

my class 'tree' contains a check_balance() function definition inside, but when i try to print it it says it's not defined.. even though it should be. could you tell me what i'm doing wrong? this has happened many times and i cannot understand. thanks

```
class tree():
    def __init__(self,a=None,lc=None,rc=None):
        self.label=a
        self.lt=lc
        self.rt=rc
        if a is not None:
            if lc is None:
                self.lt=tree()
            if rc is None:
                self.rt=tree()

    def getLabel(self):
        return self.label

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.label is None

    def isLeaf(self):
        return (self.lt.isEmpty() and self.rt.isEmpty())

    def getLc(self):
        return self.lt

    def getRc(self):
        return self.rt
    
    def check_balance(t):
        if t.isLeaf() or t.isEmpty():
            return True
        if t.getLc().isEmpty() or t.getRc().isEmpty():
            return False
        return check_balance(t.getLc()) and check_balance(t.getRc())

a = tree(1, tree(2, tree(7), tree(8)), tree(3, tree(7), tree()))
print(check_balance(a))
```

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: yes i'm sorry! that's what i'm using

Comment: The correct syntax for invoking a method would be `a.check_balance()`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for this would be:

```
a.check_balance()
```